# Proper table formatting

Tags: tables, minipage, multirow, makecell

Ideally I would have vertically aligned text and notes at the bottom of the page, not of the `minipage`, and not use `multirow`.

The outer colums should take up as small as possible space, and the middle one should take up the majority. That's why I have the `0.53\linewidht` there.

I need to be able to separate sentences in the middle column, as they were bullet points, but still maintain the width.

In the following MWE are my three tries, I want to use just one method.

This code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{svg}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}%%%This is to make cool boxes
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm,bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[final]{microtype}


\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \caption{On Data.}
    \label{tab:data_section_dga}
    \begin{tabular}{l p{0.53\textwidth} r}
    \toprule
    \textbf{Topic} & \textbf{Bullet points} & \textbf{Articles/Recitals} \\
    \midrule
    \makecell[l]{bla \\ bla} & 
    \makecell{
         bla\footnote{bla} and bla\footnote{bla} \\
         bla bla bla bla bla bla bla blabla bla bla blabla bla bla blabla bla bla bla\\
            bla} 
    & Rec 3-4 \\    
        \multirow{3}{*}{bla} & bla bla bla \textit{bla}\footnote{bla} and \textit{bla}\footnote{bla}) & \multirow{3}{*}{Rec 3-4}\\
        \addlinespace
         & bla bla bla & \\
        \addlinespace
     & bla bla bla  \\
        \addlinespace
    \makecell[l]{bla \\ bla} &
    \begin{minipage}{0.53\textwidth}
        bla bla bla 
         \textit{bla}\footnote{bla} and \textit{bla}\footnote{bla}
         bla bla bla \\
bla bla bla \\ 
bla bla bla 
     \end{minipage} & bla \\
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Produces this output:
[image: output]

`\makecell` doesn't allow vertical alignment and the fact I have to manually linebreak for long text is not ideal. Using `multirow` centers vertically almost perfectly, though I think that's a mistake on my end. And `minipage` allows the text on the left to be centered, but the footnotes are on the table.

What would you do?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you are after for something like this:

[image]

- for table is used `tabularx` package
- removed is `minipage (bottom of page)
- for footnotes are used pairs `\fotnotemark` - `footnotetext`,
- for vertical centering ov cells content is used command `\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}`

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
%\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
%\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{svg}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}%%%This is to make cool boxes
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm,bindingoffset=6mm,
            showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[final]{microtype}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}%%%This is to make cool boxes

\begin{document}
\blindtext[2]
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \caption{On Data.}
    \label{tab:data_section_dga}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{l X r}
    \toprule
\textbf{Topic} & \textbf{Bullet points} & \textbf{Articles/Recitals} \\
    \midrule
\makecell[l]{bla \\ bla} 
    &   bla\footnotemark[1] and bla\footnotemark[2] 
        bla bla bla bla bla bla bla blabla bla bla blabla bla bla blabla bla bla bla
        bla
        &   Rec 3-4     \\
    \addlinespace
\multirow{3}{*}{bla} 
    &   bla bla bla \textit{bla}\footnotemark[3] and \textit{bla}\footnotemark[4] 
        &   \multirow{3}{*}{Rec 3-4}\\
    %\addlinespace
    & bla bla bla 
        &               \\
    %\addlinespace
    & bla bla bla   
        &               \\
    \addlinespace
\makecell[l]{bla \\ bla} 
    &   bla bla bla \textit{bla}\footnotemark[5] and \textit{bla}\footnotemark[6]
        bla bla bla
        &               \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\footnotetext{bla}
\footnotetext{bla}
\footnotetext{bla}
\footnotetext{bla}
\footnotetext{bla}
\footnotetext{bla}

\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Note: don't load packages two times!

**Addendum:**

- after editing your question and comment is even less clear at least to me, what you after
- so, I again guessing what this should be
- now I make the following changes:

  - introduce lists in the middle column,
  - change the first and last column settings,
  - remove all `multirow` and `\makecell` instruction in cells,
- instead `p{...}` is used `m{...}` column types

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm,bindingoffset=6mm,
            showframe]{geometry}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[final]{microtype}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{table}{%
\setlist[itemize]{nosep,
                  leftmargin=*,
                  before=\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}\raggedright,
                  after=\end{minipage}
                 }
                           }% end of AtBeginEnvironment

\usepackage{booktabs, tabularx}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\blindtext[2]
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \caption{On Data.}
    \label{tab:data_section_dga}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} m{2em} X >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{5em} @{}}
    \toprule
\textbf{Topic} & \textbf{Bullet points} & \textbf{Articles/ Recitals} \\
    \midrule
bla bla
    &   \begin{itemize}
    \item   bla\footnotemark[1] and bla\footnotemark[2]
    \item   bla bla bla bla bla bla bla blabla bla bla blabla bla bla blabla bla bla bla
    \item   bla
        \end{itemize}
        &   Rec 3-4     \\
    \addlinespace
bla
    &   \begin{itemize}
    \item   bla bla bla \textit{bla}\footnotemark[3] and \textit{bla}\footnotemark[4]
    \item   bla bla bla
    \item   bla bla bla
        \end{itemize}
        &   Rec 3-4     \\
    \addlinespace
bla bla
    &   \begin{itemize}
    \item   bla bla bla \textit{bla}\footnotemark[5] and \textit{bla}\footnotemark[6]
    \item   bla bla bla
        \end{itemize}
        &               \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\footnotetext[1]{bla}
\footnotetext[2]{bla}
\footnotetext[3]{bla}
\footnotetext[4]{bla}
\footnotetext[5]{bla}
\footnotetext[6]{bla}

\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I edited the post to be a bit more precise. For the first row in your example, is it possible to separate sentences in the middle column, as they were bullet points, but still have them properly return/linebreak (idk how to say)?